# How does hspec's shouldThrow work?

Tags: haskell

From [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-expectations-0.8.2/docs/src/Test-Hspec-Expectations.html#anyException)

```
type Selector a = (a -> Bool)

shouldThrow :: (HasCallStack, Exception e) => IO a -> Selector e -> Expectation
action `shouldThrow` p = do
  r <- try action
  case r of
    Right _ ->
      expectationFailure $
        "did not get expected exception: " ++ exceptionType
    Left e ->
      (`expectTrue` p e) $
        "predicate failed on expected exception: " ++ exceptionType ++ " (" ++ show e ++ ")"
  where
    -- a string repsentation of the expected exception's type
    exceptionType = (show . typeOf . instanceOf) p
      where
        instanceOf :: Selector a -> a
        instanceOf _ = error "Test.Hspec.Expectations.shouldThrow: broken Typeable instance"

anyException :: Selector SomeException
anyException = const True
```

Specifically why `any...Exception` always return `True` and how `instanceOf` works? Are there any documentation that explains all this?

Comment: `any<..>Exception` is `const True` because it has a type signature constraining it to operate only on values of a particular type; every `SomeException` is "any exception" (since `SomeException` is the least upper bound of exception types) and clearly every `IOException` is an "IO exception". `instanceOf` works because `typeOf` should not examine its argument; if it does, then the `Typeable` instance for that type is broken (probably an artifact from when you could manually write `Typeable` instances - that is not the case today, so `instanceOf = const undefined` would be just as good).

Comment: @user2407038 how can `any<..>Exception` type signature constraint work at runtime? about `instanceOf` - how can compiler only by type signature derive that it must build function that  excerpt `a` from `(a -> Bool)`?

Comment: 1) Because all exceptions are `Typeable`; the type of the actual exception thrown is compared against the type of the `Selector` (this logic is inside `try`), and if they match, the actual `Selector` function is applied to further select specific exceptions from those types. Thus, in the cases in question, every exception of the types `SomeException` and `IOException` will be selected. 2) I'm not sure what you mean - the compiler (more specifically, typechecker) deriving information from type signatures is basically what it does...

Comment: 1) `any...Exception` - ok, `Typeable` allows to magically compare types in type signatures, so `anyIOException IOException` return `True`, will compiler return `False` on `anyIOException ArithException` or throw error once again? 2) now I completely confused what `instanceOf` doing and what will `typeOf` get from it, can you write some examples? and what you mean by `instanceOf works because typeOf should not examine its argument`? You can write it in answer

Comment: 1) `anyIOException (x::ArithException)` is ill-typed; this application would never happen. Again, the logic is in `try`; if the exception type selected by the `Selector` matches the one actually thrown, it will apply the selector to that function. Otherwise, `try` itself will rethrow the exception. 2) There are plenty of examples on how to use `Typeable` to be found on the internet. There is little I can say to elucidate how it works beyond the host of literature already available.

Comment: This code seems to have a bit of ancient cruft in it. It should really use `typeRep` instead of `typeOf`, which would avoid this `undefined` nonsense altogether.